# Why is pip using deprecated settings?

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip

My `pip install` is trying to contact the wrong server (a server I used in the past, but now deprecated): I see this because the installation of a package is timing out. Two questions:

- Where is pip getting the (wrong) configuration from? Definitely not from `~/.pip/pip.conf` since I checked!
- How to turn *verbose* mode so that I see what requests pip is sending?

Answer (score 1):

`-v` or `--verbose` 
To enable verbose mode

Comment: Well, yes, obviously. And that shows me what server is pip accessing, which is the standard pypi server. But then, strangely enough, when pip installs downloaded package by running its setup.py, another pip instance is called there which tries to access my deprecated server, which is specified nowhere! I am out of my depth here.

Comment: So, funny funny, it was not `pip`, but `easy_install`: it seems the package that I want to install (`cairocffi==0.8.0`) installs something with `easy_install` (which I seldom use), and *that* was badly configured in `.pydistutils.cfg`. I found it by grepping the whole system for the offending server.

Comment: it's a bit too late, but happy that you have found a solution :)